# MySQL Java JDBC: How to get the name of an auto-incremented column?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm working on a program that makes using MySQL databases simpler. Right now I have to create forms to add and edit data from the tables within the database. The problem is that when I create the form I don't want to display fields for auto-incremented columns. All I need is the name of the column to fix this but I have no idea how to find the name of a auto-incremented column. I have tried looking up the answer but all I find is information about finding auto - generated keys. Can someone help me or point me in the right direction? Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for the help. Base on the answers below I came up with this method:

```
public Vector<String> getAutoIncrementedColumns(String table) {
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    Connection connection;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(getUrl(), getUser(),
                    getPassword());
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("Select * from "+table);
        int columnCount = result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for(int i = 1; i <=columnCount; i++){
            if(result.getMetaData().isAutoIncrement(i)){
                columnNames.add(result.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return columnNames;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have a `ResultSet`, you can call its `getMetaData` method to the get a [ResultSetMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) object.  From there, you can use the `isAutoIncrement` method to determine if a column is an AUTO_INCREMENT column, and `getColumnName` to get the column's name.

Answer (score 1):

The `EXTRA` column of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table should have this information.

PS:this is from top of my head. Don't have MySql handy, you may have to test to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

The class [ResultSetMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) can provide this information.

But you would have to execute a `select *` first to get a result set. You could do

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1
```

to get the result set.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the schema `information_schema` these informations are available from the tables

- TABLES (column: auto_increment, 0 = no, 1 = yes)
- COLUMNS (column: extra = auto_increment for the specific column)